# Imagick getImageBlob after compositeImage

Tags: php, imagick

I am having problems to use getImageBlob after I make a compositeImage

```
$imagick = new \Imagick();
$imagick->readImageBlob($path);
$imagick->getImageBlob(); // works

$image = new \Imagick();
$image->newImage(2400, 1800, 'none');
$image->compositeImage($imagick, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

$image->getImageBlob(); // doesn't works
```

After I do the compositeImage and try to get the imageBlob I get the following error...

```
ImagickException(code: 1): Image has no format
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a bit more work after the composite Image...

```
$image->setImageCompression(\Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$image->setImageCompressionQuality($quality);
$image->setImageFormat('jpg');
$image->setFormat('jpg');
```

After setting the format getImageBlob works!